# why is controller name repeated twice in url?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc 4.0  application, with 2 controllers and no areas. Why do i see the controller name twice in the view of controller  AzMigrationController , index action ?
For example :  `https://localhost:44348/AzMigration/AzMigration`

This is the controller signature

```
public class AzMigrationController : Controller
{
    // GET: /AzMigration/
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {    
        return View();   
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string msftAccount)
    {     
        return View("MigrationErrorPage");
    }

    public ActionResult AuthResult()
    {           
    }
```

I have the following mapRoute below

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

[image]

Comment: Does that controller have an action called `AzMigration`?

Comment: show us the code of the controller and the related action method, please. As Amy says, it seems likely you gave your action method the same name as your controller.

Comment: also let us know where you see this. if it's a link you're generating, you might be doing it wrong.

Comment: No , i don't have a action called  AzMigration. The action names are  
     [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
..
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string msftAccount)
…
        public ActionResult AuthResult()
        {


I see the double controller name when i "   return View(); " from the Index Action of AzMigrationController.

Comment: Ok so the other possibility I can think of is that you're running this from a subfolder in IIS called AzMigration. Are you using IIS or IIS Express to host the app when you run locally? Have you done anything to configure it?

Comment: no subfolders. I am running in IIS Express , from Visual Studio in debug mode.

Comment: I think i fixed it by adding this map route above default map route :

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Special",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AzMigration", action = "Index" }
            );

Comment: @user1224643 that doesn't look like the right fix. Please show the controller code and the view code. Edit the question to show those snippets.

Comment: i agree. I fixed the AzMigration controller, but broke the HOme controller.

Comment: @user1224643 can you please show the view code (CSHTML) where it's generating the (bad) link as well?

Comment: Do you maybe have route attributes in your real code, that you forgot to include in the question? I am imagining a route at controller level (specifying its name) plus one at action level, specifying both controller and action. They will be concatenated